# How to get OptionsMenu before inflated?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-optionsmenu

I'm trying to hide OptionsMenu by depend on navigation between fragment in the same activity :-

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    this.menu = menu;
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.result, menu);
    return true;

}
```

And i hide it by depend on fragment position like :

```
if (newStepPosition == 0) {
        if (menu != null){
            menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.resultGroup, false);
        }
    }
    if (newStepPosition == 1) {
            if (menu != null){
            menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.resultGroup, true);
        }

    }
```

My issue is that i must see the optionMenu for the first time i created the activity then the hide and appear thread work, how to avoid that ?

I need to hide the optionMenu in `onCreat()` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't hide menu from `onCreate` method since it's not inflated yet.

Try using this:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    menu.clear();

    // do what you want

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Otherwise, put your logic in `onCreateOptionsMenu` method and call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` when you need to refresh something.

Answer (score 0):

I done with that in onCreateOptionsMenu, and after that appearance logic work perfectly.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    this.menu = menu;
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.result, menu);
    if (menu != null){
        menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.resultGroup, false);
    }
    return true;

}
```